# Layout rendering measurement in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to measure and compare how long does it take to inflate or better to render a layout.
Seems like best way with Android SDK that I found is

```
val frameMetricsHandler = Handler()
window.addOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener({ _, frameMetrics, _ ->
    val metrics = FrameMetrics(frameMetrics)
    Log.d("Metrics", metrics.getMetric(FrameMetrics.LAYOUT_MEASURE_DURATION))
}, frameMetricsHandler)
```

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener.html

But what would be the equivalent of that in Flutter? Or does anyone have better measuring approach (for rendering screen) that could be applied to both SDKs?

Comment: In dev or in release?

Comment: dev is enough, for flutter i suppose profile debug

Answer (score 0):

To manually measure how long it takes for a widget to load, use the built-in [DevTools performance chart](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance).

If you are looking for a way to do this programmatically, such as in a benchmark, see the documentation on [performance profiling of integration tests](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/profiling),